# Laravel and Angular.JS - Web App Dev

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I have started learning Laravel and Angular, for one of my project at university. I want to rebuild the website www.lolcalculator.com with these two frameworks but I cant figure out exatly the best way to do that. From Laravel I want the less posible, because I will focus on Angular. 
Can someone with more experience help me?
For example, do I need to use routing on both sides? Which functions of the website I should cover with Laravel(Mailer, Auth, Routing...) and which using Angular?
I just need to understand a bigger image, not in details.
Tnx a lot.
All the best :D

Answer (score 0):

There's quite some information on the net regarding Laravel and Angular, but this one in particular is one that I found useful: http://scotch.io/tutorials/php/create-a-laravel-and-angular-single-page-comment-application.

You may also want to consider writting a front-end app in Angular and a separate back-end app in Laravel. The back-end app can then expose an API, consumed by the Angular front-end.